# Why is there difference between the errorlevels in these two cases?

Tags: cmd, taskkill, errorlevel

Scenario 1:
calc.exe is running

```
taskkill /IM calc.exe /f | if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /IM calc.exe /f
```

This sets 1 as the errorlevel.

Scenario 2: calc.exe is not running

```
taskkill /IM calc.exe /f
```

This sets 128 as the errorlevel.

Can someone please explain me why this happens and if there is a way to get errorlevel as 128 in the first scenario as well similar to the second one?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with `taskkill`, `tasklist` and `find`.  All return inconsistent errorlevels.  That makes it ***impossible*** to reliably use errorlevel to know if the process is running or if it has truly been terminated.  However, I did find a way to do it without using errorlevel:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set _i=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('tasklist ^| find /i "%1"') do set /a _i+=1

if !_i! GTR 0 (

  echo Found !_i! instances of %1.  Terminating all instances...
  taskkill /im "%1" /f > nul 2>&1

  echo Verifying that %1 has been terminated...
  set _i=0
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('tasklist ^| find /i "%1"') do set /a _i+=1

  if !_i! EQU 0 (
    echo %1 was successfully terminated.
  ) else (
    echo %1 was *not* teriminated.  There are still !_i! instances running.
  )

) else (
  echo %1 is not running.
)

set _i=
endlocal
```

You need to enable delayed expansion, so that the `_i` variable can be properly evaluated.

The `for ... %%i` line of code sets `_i` equal to the number of instances that the process is in memory.  Since `find` doesn't return a consistent errorlevel, we can use this technique to reliably find the # of times it is in memory...